Ubuntu RAID1 won't boot
This is a machine I am remote from, so cannot do the obvious (look at what is happening in a console).
The machine has 4 drives: sda, sdb, sdc, and sdd. sda and sdb are configured as one software RAID1, and sdc and sdd are configured as one software RAID1.
Personalities : [raid1] [linear] [multipath] [raid0] [raid6] [raid5] [raid4] [raid10] 
md0 : active raid1 sda3[0] sdb3[2]
     3877589824 blocks super 1.2 [2/2] [UU]

md1 : active raid1 sdb4[2] sda4[0]
     4877248 blocks super 1.2 [2/2] [UU]

md3 : active raid1 sdc1[2] sdd1[1](F)
     3906886272 blocks super 1.2 [2/1] [U_]

md2 : active raid1 sda5[0] sdb5[2]
     18538368 blocks super 1.2 [2/2] [UU]

As you can see device sdd failed. It failed so hard that /dev/sdd was not present in the system. Where I then made a mistake was that I thought if the device wasn't there, RAID wouldn't recognise it, so I did not need to do
mdadm --manage /dev/md3 --fail /dev/sdd1
mdadm --manage /dev/md3 --remove /dev/sdd1

In retrospect I need not have executed the first of those lines, but I should have executed the second of them. Oops.
I shut down the machine remotely and my helpful "remote hands" removed the drive, checked the serial number was as expected, and replaced it with a new drive. The machine did not reboot (there is no monitor or keyboard and attaching one is awkward). We then replaced the new drive with the old drive again (having realised my error), and rebooted. Again it would not reboot.
Any idea what has happened here and how to fix it? I am guessing a site visit may be necessary - which will involve an international flight!
The boot partition is on md0 (from memory) - definitely the other disk pair. md3 is /var/backup or similar. It's mounted on boot but is not vital.

IPMI is your friend...

Or boot a live system and perform diagnostics such as re-installing boot loader from the live system (chroot is possibly your friend)

You have to see the output. It can be literally anything. Having a not-booting server is awkward, connecting a display to fix it is not. Also, IP KVM is a great invention, but IPMI SoL and sort of built-in IP KVM provided by nearly all BMCs (built into server motherboards) is even greater, and not nearly as awkward.
